# Embedding HTML snippets from GitHub in a page with Django

Tags: django, iframe, github

I'm building a simple personal site in Django, the main mission of which is to embed my GitHub projects inside blog posts so I can write about them in detail.

The GitHub projects are all self-contained HTML/CSS/JS projects and include the HTML files that demo the project. (For example, this [Javascript metronome](https://github.com/wilson428/metronome) has a `demo.html` file that, if rendered, embeds the metronome and so forth.)

I have a nimble blog post model that allows for custom code of any sort, but I'm sure there's a better way to embed this project than pasting the HTML+CSS for the demo into the body text of the post and calling the JS files.

I do **not** want to use an `<iframe>`, so I'm thinking there should be a server-side way to load the HTML from the demo pages and its dependencies on GitHub directly onto the page before it is served to the reader. If necessary, I can keep up-to-date clones on the server to get around cross-domain issues.

Or maybe there's a better way to embed GitHub projects on a page? Gist?

Comment: why all the hate for the iframe?  this is exactly what the iframe was made for.

Comment: I find that too many mobile devices strip them.